# fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all

Tags: php, git, shell-exec, git-pull

I'm trying to preform a 'git pull origin master' from a shell exec on a cpanel server however I keep getting the error 'fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all.'

The script I'm running is

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('git pull origin master 2>&1');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Other git commands work as expected so I don't know why git pull specifically doesn't work.

I was reading a similar question on the topic and it suggested to use the command:

```
/usr/bin/git pull origin master 2>&1
```

however there is no output from this command at all. It also suggests to look from the binary git-pull in usr/bin/ which does not exists in my case however the git binary does.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: If your sure you have git installed, find out where it is `whereis git` then if its in say `/usr/bin/git` then add the full path to your cmd. `echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/git pull origin master')` - If you don't have it installed then  nothing will work.

Comment: whereis git outputs /usr/bin/git. Where I call echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/git pull origin master 2>&1')  I get the same error '/usr/bin/git pull origin master 2>&1'